# leaving ruby on rails incorrect callback as is wondering if it will break

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I received a small contract doing ruby on rails work. I am allotted 100 hours and I am almost 75 hours into the work. We got a deadline coming up. The app is already behind schedule.

My employer is working with another company on this app for the same client. There are parts of the app that I am not allowed to touch.

I was given the task to write some rspec/capybara test for the other company's models (code that I should not touch).

anyway please see model below

```
class Graph < ActiveRecord::Base
  #cut out some stuff

  has_many :graph_revisions, -> { select "id, graph_id, template, css, version, created_at, updated_at" }


  validates :title, presence: true
  #validates :system_name, presence: true

  before_create do
    self.title = title.downcase
    self.system_name = title_to_system_name(self.title)
  end

  after_destroy do
    graph_revisions.each do |graph|
      graph.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

I was writing tests (trying to make them pass) etc and noticed that the callbacks look like they aren't implemented correctly......

I think the stuff inside the before_create do block should be in its own methods and the after destroy seems unnecessary because you can throw in a `dependent destroy` in the `has_many` relationships.

All callbacks for all models look like that.

```
class GroupInstance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :graph
  #cut out some stuff
  validates :graph_id, presence: true


  before_save do
    self.name = name.downcase
  end
end
```

and I don't think validating graph_id is necessary for the 2nd model as well.

We will launch this small app on either heroku or lease a server and it will be sitting around for a while.

My question is will the callbacks break? it is absolutely necessary to fix? I am not experienced enough to know how long code like this can stand/used by people. Its a college application app and there will be users when school starts again.

Comment: I've not seen that syntax before, the way I do it is `before_save :some_method` then `def some_method
    self.name = name.downcase`
  end` but I'm currently using Rails 2. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: It doesn't look like it will break, just like you say some things could be done better.  Can't you give a list of reccommendations to the other company?

Comment: @martincarlin87 I was thinking of the same thing!

Comment: @Baloo I can but last time I did, it was not a good response. good that I know it won't break. thanks!

Comment: @martincarlin87 it's perfectly valid to pass a block to a callback.  I would only use it for one liners e.g. `before_save { self.name = name.downcase }` I wouldn't use `do` and `end` if you have a few lines I would do as you suggest.  But to be honest that's really more just personal preference

Comment: @Jngai1297 in which case I would tell your concerns to your boss who can then deal with it however they wish.

Comment: the syntax is fine... though perhaps not the approach I would use when writing those models... I like passing methods to callbacks as, if your method is named well, it gives some added readability by declaring right at the top of the class what it does when... but it is a personal preference... as far as the validation of graph_id goes... it may not be necessary but is generally good practice to validate anything that the model expects to exist (as the ui is subject to change and it also makes creating things through the console or programmatically a bit nicer with .save!)...